# How can I save a Superfeedr feed to a database?

Tags: postgresql, azure, superfeedr

I want to subscribe to several RSS feeds at once, and save the contents to a database.  I have a Superfeedr account, so I can subscribe to the feeds that way, but I've read the Superfeedr docs and I can't figure out how I then access the aggregated feed to do anything with it.

I have an Azure account with a PostgresQL database which I can use to save the information, but I'm not sure whether there's a 'best' way to do that - I'm happy to use PHP, C, JS or something else, but I don't really know where to actually put the code to make it work.  Do I set up a cron job or some kind of timeout, or can I get Superfeedr to automatically send updates to a listener?

Answer (score 1):

I created Superfeedr many years ago :)
Superfeedr uses webhooks which means that once you have subscribed, you will receive notifications which include the content of the updated feeds on your HTTP server (you can ise PHP, JS or even C if you feel adventurous!)
These notifications will be POST requests and you just have to parse the body.

Comment: I don't think I'm really clear how this works, to be honest.  So, in Superfeedr, I go into my Subscriptions and I can see 'FeedURL', 'End point' and 'Format' (I didn't add the original feed, so I don't know whether those are autogenerated?). I have 1 feed, which has the end point https://push.superfeedr.com/dev/null.  What do I do with that?

Comment: Well, the endpoint is where Superfeedr would send the notification. Clearly the one you have there will not help. You should deploy an HTTP server and put the URL of your listener on that server instead of this superfeedr.com URL.